# How can I print with the header and footer in silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

How can I print with the header and footer which I paas dynamically in silverlight 4 ?

Please provide me some example.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice example: http://10rem.net/blog/2010/05/09/creating-a-simple-report-writer-in-silverlight-4